# Json array getting first data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array which I declared as var `myclinicsID = new Array();` and now, I push some data in it,when I alert it using `alert(JSON.stringify(myclinicsID))` it gives me output of `["1","2","3","4"]`

Now I want to use this for my function and when I look at in console, it gives me undefined, am I doing correct by my code :

```
getbarSeriesData(myclinicsID[0]['clinic_id'],data[i]['datemonths']);
```

I want to get myclinicsID first data element which is the value is 1

Comment: You don't have anything by `clinic_id` in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myclinicsID[0]['clinic_id']
```

Should be

```
myclinicsID[0]
```

All you need the array index. When you say `myclinicsID[0]['clinic_id']`, that is trying to get the `clinic_id` property of `"1"` which is obvious undefined.

Comment: hello sir, since it was easy for you. can i ask another regardng with array?

Comment: @JcJohn You can ask.

Comment: opps hello sir can we discuss something? @ANS

Comment: for (var i in data) {
       categories.push(data[i]["datemonths"]);
       var innerLoop = 0
          for(var i in data) {
                    
            getbarSeriesData(myclinicsID[0],data[i]['datemonths']);
            
            innerLoop++;
          }
     }
i have two loops and in my second loop, i want the length of my array to be the end of looping before going back to the outer loop

Answer (score 2):

Why **`myclinicsID[0]['clinic_id']`** ? As there is nothing like `clinic_id` in your array.

Your array is single dimensional array. Hence, you can directly access the first element from an array using `myclinicsID[0]`.

**DEMO**

```js
var myclinicsID = new Array();
myclinicsID[0] = 1;
myclinicsID[1] = 2;
myclinicsID[2] = 3;
myclinicsID[3] = 4;

function getbarSeriesData(clientID) {
  console.log(clientID);
  alert(clientID);
}

getbarSeriesData(myclinicsID[0]);
```

Comment: hello @Rohit, i have another question can you help me?

Comment: hello. why is this not working ? alert(myclinicsID[0]);

Comment: `alert(myclinicsID[0])` is working fine. I updated my answer you can check now.

Comment: getbarSeriesData(myclinicsID[0],data[i]['datemonths']); ,
in my console i got POST 
XHR 
http://localhost/clinic/patients_report/get_checkup/March/undefined

Comment: why mine says undefine?

Comment: check my updated answer. It will work as per ypur expectation.